# Is there a Magento 2 equivalent of Drupal's "variable_set"?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to store persistent values (e.g. system settings, etc) in Magento 2. In Drupal you can use variable_set and variable_get to quickly do this without worrying about the DB calls involved.

Is there a way to do it in Magento 2? I see that there are tables called `variable` and `variable_value`, but there doesn't seem to be any information about them out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables would relate to what you enter under
System > Other Settings > Custom Variables
these you could use with `{{customVar code='EXAMPLE_CODE'}}` in places where these are processed (CMS pages and email templates for example).

However if you are looking to store and retrieve system settings I suggest using Magento's way of doing this. In broad strokes:

1.) create an `adminhtml/system.xml` file - that displays your setting in the back-end under Stores > Configuration and will automatically handle things like multistore for you (it's saved in core_config_data if you are curious)

2.) retrieve the setting via

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        path/to/setting,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $storeId
    );
```

with `scopeConfig` being of type `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`.